# Git alternative to a shelveset in TFS

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

I use git for my personal projects, so I have never run into any issues with Git, however I had a discussion at work today and its something that I haven't thought about.

In TFS you can store your changeset into a shelveset, this shelveset can be viewed by other developers, say for a peer review.

From what I understand in github you are working on your local copy of the repo (possibly with custom branches for different features) and then comes a point for a peer review. How would you go about sharing a specific changes on your local repo with someone else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Git, the basic model for pre-commit code review is to have a branch somewhere where it can bee reviewed, then merged with the main stream. This branch may be in the same repository as the main stream or in a completely separate one.

Some ways that I've seen done are:

1. Push a branch to origin, and have the reviewers merge the changeset in when they're ready.
2. Push a branch to a review repository or directly to the reviewer. Once reviewed the changeset may be pushed to the main repository.
3. Use a tool like [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) to "catch" pushes and hold them until they're reviewed. Once the right people have confirmed the changeset is ready, Gerrit will merge it into the main branch.
4. Using [Github](https://github.com/), [Gitlab](https://www.gitlab.com/), [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash) or another product, fork the original repository. Clone to your development machine and perform your changes. When finished, push to your fork and send a pull request to the original repository. This is the most common model in the open source world.

Comment: 0. Visual Studio Online has a Pull-request feature that will be available in a near future version of TFS on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. You could run an instance of [gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) to allow others to view your changes
2. You could distribute patch sets of your changes for review
3. You could push your changes to a shared central repo, in your own remote branch, where others can inspect your changes directly or in github.